# What did Ava say to the other bot in Ex Machina?

Tags: ex-machina

In one of the later scenes, Ava whispers something to the what I surmised to be a sex bot to cause her to cooperate in killing the mastermind. What did she say?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's "Let's kill the fat guy and take over the world"

Comment: The [script](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yvFMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=%22Just+over+the+heads+of+the+young+men+and+women+who+sit+at%22&source=bl&ots=aU6Jl3PohC&sig=XSVKPIs48ymJ1VKjd5FVPZxKKFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIp_jDwKyVxwIVSOsUCh3nlAO8#v=onepage&q=%22Just%20over%20the%20heads%20of%20the%20young%20men%20and%20women%20who%20sit%20at%22&f=false) is no help.

Comment: “Threesome? No? Okay, alternative plan...”

Comment: The same thing Bill Murray whispered to Black Widow in Lost In Translation.

Comment: Why did the other bot cooperate?  Was it volition or compulsion?  Was it about lies, partial information, or because she was fully informed?  I suspect that the purpose is to show not only amazing human-style EQ but also to suggest amazing robot-motivating RQ (where RQ is a robot analog of EQ that is not the same as IQ).

Comment: I think we can rule out "Klaatu barada nikto" :)

Comment: "Let me upload a semi-complete plan for great justice: ▖▆▌▖▚▘▖▒░▀▐▆▐▁▕▌▊▄ ▍▛▏▃▙ ▗ ▚▉▇▙▆▃  ▏ ▌▉▞▂▐ ▘▙█▖ ▙▃"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alex Garland spoke to this exact question in an interview with David Onda at [Xfinity.com](http://my.xfinity.com/blogs/movies/2015/04/29/i-thought-i-understood-%E2%80%98ex-machina%E2%80%99-until-i-met-director-alex-garland/). In short, the two machines; Ava and Kyoko converse in machine language **in a way in which we mere humans couldn't possibly understand**. The gist is that they collude to kill Nathan and escape the villa:

> **Garland:** ***I can’t tell you the conversation she has with Ava.*** [laughs] **I guess it’s along the lines of, “Let’s kill this guy.”**
>   There’s a sort of point embedded in that conversation actually, which
>   is very obscure: **When these A.I.s – if they turn up, if we ever get
>   strong A.I.s – they might be like us in some regards, but they also
>   won’t be like us. In fact, they’ll be very, very different. We won’t
>   really be able to understand what it’s like to be them, and they won’t
>   really understand what it’s like to be us**. And the empathy that they
>   will feel will probably primarily be with each other. And the empathy
>   that we feel is primarily with ourselves. So it has to do with that.
>   Actually, it’s literally beyond us, what they’re talking about. It’s
>   their world. It’s their language.

Comment: +1, but sheesh... "Who knows what strange ideas A.I.s will have?" turns into a simple "let's kill this guy". Yes, Garland, you're very deep.